# simple bash script, how can I make it shorter and better?

Tags: linux, bash

I wanna a bash command to move to a directory, and then show 2 files' content for each entry, I made this script:

```
cd /sys/class/net
for i in *; do echo $i; cat $i/{address,operstate}; done
```

is there anyway to do shorter and better?

Comment: Why do you want to "optimize" it? Don't optimize for optimization's sake.

Comment: for simplicity, I wanna do it with just one command.

Comment: The script above looks very simple and easy to understand. Any shorter script is likely to be more complex (requiring pipes, xargs, etc, etc). That isn't necessarily a bad thing - but you won't be making it more "simple"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep and sort can give a similar answer

```
(cd /sys/class/net/;grep -T '' */{addre,o}*|sort)
```

Example output

```
eth0/address   :10:9a:dd:6e:66:33
eth0/operstate :down
lo/address     :00:00:00:00:00:00
lo/operstate   :unknown
wlan0/address  :e0:f8:47:20:b3:92
wlan0/operstate:up
```

I really liked the answer using tail, but unfortunately it keep the address and operstate next to each other. Using grep, I can fix this with sort. But it's not one command, sorry.

The -T option to grep does the aligning (using a tab)

Answer (score 1):

No need for the `cd`. Try the following:

`for i in /sys/class/net/*; do echo "${i##/*/}:"; cat $i/{address,operstate}; done`

This should give you an output like this:

```
eth2: 
0f:ed:37:1f:6c:c7
up
lo: 
00:00:00:00:00:00
unknown
wlan0: 
94:58:29:b6:07:3e
down
```

The `echo` above removes the leading path elements using bash parameter
substitution to make the output prettier.

Comment: @fluter The real question here is: what do you consider better; fewer utilities, fewer characters typed or easier concepts? I personally think better means more portable hence use of shell features than external tools like grep, sed or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I just found tail can do simpler,

```
 tail /sys/class/net/*/{address,operstate}
```

this is only one command, without pips and compound shell statements. :) – fluter just now edit